# Setup Apereo Cas Management integrated with CAS server

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, apereo

I want to install Apero Cas Management [(verison 6.0)](https://github.com/apereo/cas-management-overlay/tree/6.0) and  integrate it with  Cas Server ([version 6.0](https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template/tree/6.0)).

I have installed following these step:

Step 1: I installed Cas Server

I checked it with REST API. It worked.

My server stays at http://203.162.141.7:8080

[image]

[image]

And this is configuration of my Cas server. I put this config at `/etc/cas/config`. Here is my file cas.properties file

```
cas.server.name=http://203.162.141.7:8080
cas.server.prefix=${cas.server.name}/cas

logging.config: file:/etc/cas/config/log4j2.xml
server.port=8080
server.ssl.enabled=false

cas.serviceRegistry.initFromJson=false
cas.serviceRegistry.json.location=file:/etc/cas/services-repo

cas.authn.oauth.grants.resourceOwner.requireServiceHeader=true
cas.authn.oauth.userProfileViewType=NESTED

cas.authn.policy.requiredHandlerAuthenticationPolicyEnabled=false

cas.authn.attributeRepository.stub.attributes.email=casuser@example.org
#REST API JSON
cas.rest.attributeName=email
cas.rest.attributeValue=.+example.*
```

Step 2: I installed Cas-management-overlay

I put my cas-management-overlay's config file a `/etc/cas/config` too. Here is my management.properties file

```
cas.server.name=http://203.162.141.7:8080
cas.server.prefix=${cas.server.name}/cas
mgmt.serverName=http://203.162.141.7:8088
mgmt.adminRoles[0]=ROLE_ADMIN
mgmt.userPropertiesFile=file:/etc/cas/config/users.json
server.port=8088
server.ssl.enabled=false
logging.config=file:/etc/cas/config/log4j2-management.xml
```

And my here is `users.json` file

```
{
  "casuser" : {
   "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.mgmt.authz.json.UserAuthorizationDefinition",
   "roles" : [ "ROLE_ADMIN" ]
     }
}
```

Then I run `./build.sh`, and it shows me that

[image]

Finally, I access this link to open cas-management `http://203.162.141.7:8088/cas-management`, but the it redirects to this url `http://203.162.141.7:8080/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2F203.162.141.7%3A8088%2Fcas-management%2F` and shows this error below

[image]

I don't know where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think since you haven't told the management webapp about the location of the service registry, it can't add itself as a registered service.

Manually add a registered service for `http://203.162.141.7:8088/cas-management` and you should be able to log in to the management app at that point.

Comment: Could you show me how to add a registered service, please? I don't know this.

Comment: You'll need to create a file in `/etc/cas/services-repo` according to https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.1.x/services/JSON-Service-Management.html#json-syntax and do note the naming convention for those files on that page.

Comment: Thanks, let's me try this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer for cas-management register file name `/etc/cas/services-repo/casManagement-1.json`

```
{
  "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  "serviceId":"^https://domain:8088/cas-management.+",
   "name" : "casManagement",
   "id" : 1,
   "evaluationOrder" : 1,
   "allowedAttributes":["cn","mail"]
}
```